# Amazon MWS: Convert ASIN to EAN/UPC

Tags: amazon-mws

I have a list of ASINs and need to get the corresponding EAN/UPC values.

I am aware this is possible using AWSECommerceService and ItemLookup call. However, my application already uses MWS, and I'd like to avoid using two APIs, two access keys, etc.

The most similar API call in MWS is GetMatchingProduct. However, the returned data does not include an EAN/UPC. I would be astonished if this is impossible with MWS, however, I can't see anyway to get EAN/UPC.

Any suggestions appreciated,

Paul

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a call that does what you want. There is a call that does the opposite, if that is of any help: GetMatchingProductFromId will return the ASIN for a given EAN or UPC. Why the result from this call (and from GetMatchingProduct) does not return EANs etc. is beyond me.

If you already have items listed through MWS, the [_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_ report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676329/amazon-mws-report-type-get-merchant-listings-data-result-attributes-meaning/16725724#16725724) might help

Comment: Thanks for the answer... unfortunately the _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_ does not include EAN/UPC. And I do need to go from ASIN to EAN/UPC. I'm actually starting with the output of a similar report, and matching it to data on an existing EPOS system using barcodes.

Comment: Whether that report includes EAN/UPC info may be dependant on whether you uploaded that information yourself, but I'm not sure. Unfortunately, it seems MWS does not have a call that does what you're looking for, so you'll have to get a separate AWS key.

Answer (score 2):

Just answering this question for my own amusement and because I might need it in the future when I have forgotten I previously looked at this.

Amazon apparently consider EAN for ASIN/SellerSKU proprietary information which is  why their standard seller APIs don't return it. This doesn't make a huge amount of sense to me personally because you would think that it would at least return them for your own products (when specifying your own sku and authentication information.)

I've combed the documentation, mws forums and also asked Amazon directly but it looks like it's not available through standard APIs.

I've ready somewhere that it may be possible via APIs available to associates but that's not me so remains a rumour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The information is available from AWSECommerceService.