# Convert ASIN to GTIN (EAN)

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I'm wondering how to translate ASIN identifiers to EAN one.

I searched during 1h for static computation ASIN -> EAN based on a mysterious rule. It is possible EAN -> ASIN/UPC - ISBN -> EAN. But **not** for my ASIN -> EAN case.

So I started to look into AWS API but I can't figure out which service could help me.

Moreover [it seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644922/amazon-mws-convert-asin-to-ean-upc) (mean not sure it's old) that ASIN to EAN conversion is property of amazon.

To conclude, if anybody have ever deal with this usecase pleaseeee show yourself ..! ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Amazon seller account, you can try the algopix API.

Their online tool (https://algopix.com/tools/asin-to-ean) claims that you can do this through their API, which is free to use if you have an Amazon seller account.

At least their online tool is the only one I have found so far that works efficiently in this case (converting ASIN to EAN).

https://algopix.com/xapp/pricing